# Nonlinear Partial DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

In my work I have faced with following partial differential equation

$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+f(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$

where $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(y^2-x^2)^2}{xy(x^2+y^2)}$, $u=u(x,y)$

I've tried to solve it by [method of characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Fully_nonlinear_case), but it was too complicated.

Maybe someone knows something about this type of PDE? Anyway I would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(y^2-x^2)^2}{xy(x^2+y^2)}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$

$2xy(x^2+y^2)\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+(x^2-y^2)^2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}-2xy(x^2+y^2)\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=0$

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{-(x^2-y^2)^2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\pm\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)^4\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+16x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)^2\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2}}{4xy(x^2+y^2)}$

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{-(x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4)\pm(x^4+6x^2y^2+y^4)}{4xy(x^2+y^2)}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ (according to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E4%2B16x%5E2y%5E2%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2)

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ or $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2xy}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

Comment: perfect hint, it's some kind of magic. Thx a lot. :)

Comment: @Oiale The magic is that it can factorize into two first-order quasilinear PDEs.